# Batch converting .eps to .jpg in imagemagick and making .mkv

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, batch-processing, eps

I am trying to convert multiple .eps files into .jpg ones. By looking at answers here in SO, I was able to do it for single separate files.

The problem is that, when I'm trying to do it for all the files, they don't show any .jpg file.

I am currently using Imagemagick with the command

```html
convert -density 300 outputs-000.eps -flatten outputs-000.jpg
```

I believe the problem is because my files are written as

```html
outputs-000.eps
outputs-001.eps
outputs-002.eps
outputs-003.eps
...
outputs-145.eps
...
```

and so on. I tried putting %d (as in outputs-%d.eps and outputs-%d.jpg), but with no success.

Apart from that, I intent to get all those files and "convert" them into an .mkv or .gif or similar type (they are images of the time configuration of a particle collision system, so each image is a frame, so the goal is to make it into a 10sec movie). If there is a way to do that directly from the .eps, even better. Any help is welcome, since I've been trying to do this for several hours now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to make an animated GIF in one go like this:

```
convert -density 300 outputs-*eps -delay 200 animated.gif
```

Failing that, you should be able to convert all your `eps` files to, say `PNG` with:

```
mogrify -density 300 -format png outputs-*eps
```

Be careful with mogrify - it overwrites your input files unless you specify `-path` for an output directory, or you change format - like I just did to `PNG`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who lands here trying to figure out how to work around ImageMagic's `convert: not authorized` without reverting the change that was made to the system-wide security policy to close a vulnerability, here's how you'd use Ghostscript to do a batch EPS-to-JPEG conversion directly without bringing ImageMagick into the mix:

```sh
gs -dSAFER -dEPSCrop -r300 -sDEVICE=jpeg -o outputs-%03d.jpg outputs-*.eps
```

- `-dSAFER` puts Ghostscript in a sandboxed mode where Postscript code can only interact with the files you specified on the command line. (Yes, the parts of EPS, PS, and PDF files that define the page contents [are in a turing-complete programming language](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_NXz7I5dQc).)
- `-dEPSCrop` asks for the rendered output to be cropped to the bounding box of the drawing rather than padded out to whatever size page Ghostscript expects you to be printing to. (See [the manual](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#EPS_parameters) for details.)
- The `-r300` requests 300 DPI (`-r600` for 600 DPI, etc.)
- The `-sDEVICE` specifies the output format (See the [Devices section](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.21/Devices.htm#JFIF) of the manual for other choices.)
- `-o` is a shorthand for `-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=`
- [This section](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#One_page_per_file) of the Ghostscript manual gives some example formats for for multi-file filename output but, for the actual syntax definition, it points you at the documentation for the C [printf(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) function.

Once you've got your JPEGs, you can follow the instructions in [this answer over on the Video Production Stack Exchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/7913) to combine them into an MKV file.

The TL;DR is this command here:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i outputs-%03d.jpg -codec copy output.mkv
```

Check out the other answers if you want something that performs inter-frame compression rather than aiming to avoid transcoding the JPEGs again.

(If you want the best compromise, have Ghostscript output PNGs and then let ffmpeg handle switching to lossy compression.)